# How to read each row of excel file into a list so as to make whole data a list of list?

Tags: python, excel, list, dataframe

I have a data in excel file:

2 6 67 89 9 5564 23 67 97 45

4 5

6 8 67 68 57 46 23 34 56

8 76 32 98 79 24 65 75

12 6 65 98 43 45 78 45 98

23 56 76 98 45 32 34 45 76 9

45 43 76 98 68 98 89

67 12 76 23 34 45 65 23 34 765

89 23 98 90 45 43 67

98 34 12 76 32 3 86 8 78

and i want to read each row as a list so that my desired output will be a list of lists containing each row as a list:

Desired output needs to look like and the data should not convert itself into string:

```
[[2 6 67 89 9 5564 23 67 97 45] [ 4 5] [6 8 67 68 57 46 23 34 56] 
 [8 76 32 98 79 24 65 75]  
 [12 6 65 98 43 45 78 45 98] [23 56 76 98 45 32 34 45 76 9] 
 [45 43 76 98 68 98 89]
 [67 12 76 23 34 45 65 23 34 765] [89 23 98 90 45 43 67]
[98 34 12 76 32 3 86 8 78]]
```

Actually i had tried with pandas but the problem with pandas is that it frames equal length of row for each row and mark empty column as NaN and when i keep_default_na=False then all my data is converted into string which i don't want . So i don't want to work with pandas data frame.

Any resource or reference will be helpful

Thanks

Comment: I'd just use a low level Python text read - read each line, split, and convert to individual strings to integers, collecting values in a list of lists.  Your variable line length goes against everything that `numpy` and `pandas` are expected to do.

Comment: @hpaulj - exactly, so removed pandas and numpy tags

Comment: actually this is an example data for variable length of rows and real data is 1000x7000 so I don't thinks it's a good idea to do that

Comment: @Razeun what character is the column separator? have you defined it?

Comment: no i haven't ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i had sorted this issue after some hit and trials and here is the code goes:

```
listoflist=[]
loc=('Your filename ')
a=xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
b=a.sheet_by_index(0)
for i in range(0,b.nrows):
    rli=[]
    for j in range(0,b.ncols):
        if b.cell_value(i,j) !='':
            rli.append(b.cell_value(i,j))
    listoflist.append(rli)
```

Though it solved my problem but if someone can optimize or can make this code more efficient then most welcome.